# Proxy angular request with node to service situated at azurewebsites

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, azure-web-app-service, http-proxy

I need to make some proxy post request and get response from a target of this request. Here is my server.js file code: The problem that there isn't any response after proxy request. Here are parts of my server.js connected with proxy:

```
 var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

 var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
     secure: true,
     changeOrigin: true
 });

app.post('/v1/*', function(req, res) {
    apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: 
    'http://somesite.azurewebsites.net'});
    });
});
```

Currently I works at localhost:3000 and I have tested this proxy working with localhost:8888 (another local server) and it works perfect.

Also if I remove `changeOrigin: true` there is 404 response from azurewebsite "Page not exist".
Service are workable (tested with postman).

Can't find the problem. Will be glad not only answers but even some additional sources about node&proxy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with `http-proxy`, but it's probably easier to use [request](https://github.com/request/request) when proxying some of the requests. You could do something similar with the following code:

```
var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/v1/*', function(req, res) {
    var newurl = 'http://somesite.azurewebsites.net';
    request(newurl).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(3000);
```